# Why is there need for each() method in jQuery? Isn't $('.mycls1').css(etc) more natural?

Tags: jquery

Why I cannot just write `$('.highlight').css(etc)` to set style for all html elements with `class='highlight'` ? It is the most natural way, besides in CSS it is done in this way: `.highlight { some css }`

```
<p class="highlight me">Highlight me</p>
<p class="Don't highlight">Do not highlight me</p>
<p class="highlight me">Highlight me</p>

<script>
   $('.highlight').each(function(){        <!-- why use each() ? -->  
      $(this).css("background","yellow");   
   });
</script>
```

Comment: `.each` isn't for operations like that, it's mostly for when you want to perform a _non-chainable_ method on each element in the set.    Doing `$('.highlight').css(...)` works perfectly.

Comment: *"Why I cannot just write..."*: well, you can. Did you try it? It works fine without the `each`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.each()` method is a way of looping through elements whilst returning the jQuery object for each one making `$(this)` available to you for each element. If all you want to do is perform the same function on all elements with the same class, you probably won't need the `.each()` method, and can chain methods such as `$(el).css()` instead.